# How to fix "MultiValueDictKeyError at /accounts/logout"

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am getting an error as shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler Durden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler Durden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler Durden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler Durden\Desktop\ProductHunt\accounts\views.py", line 10, in signup
    if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
  File "C:\Users\Tyler Durden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'password1'
[24/Apr/2019 04:39:23] "POST /accounts/logout HTTP/1.1" 500 74823
```

***signup.html***

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
Username:
<br />
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br />
Password:
<br />
<input type="password" name="password1" />
<br />
Confirm Password:
<br />
<input type="password" name="password2" />
<br />
<br />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type"submit" value="Sign Up!">
```

***base.html***

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> 
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}">Logout</a>
      </li>
      <form id ="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" />
      </form>

      {% else %}
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Signup</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

    </ul>
```

***views.py***

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        #User to sign a up for an account
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:    
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 
                              'accounts/signup.html', 
                              {'error': 'Username has already been taken'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'],
                                                password = request.POST['password1'], 
                                                email= request.POST['emailaddress'])
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 
                          'accounts/signup.html', 
                          {'error': 'Password entries do not match'})
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],
                                 password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 
                          'accounts/login.html', 
                          {'error': 'Username or Password is incorrect'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('home')
    #TODO Need to route to homepage and Log them out
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

Comment: Check your route configurations. Usually it named as "url.py" in your project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally routed your `logout` path to the `login` view in `urls.py`. Make sure you have your url look something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to these codes, I wrote these for django bootcamp course and worked for me :

**signup.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}"">
   {% csrf_token %}
   User name :
   <br />
      <input type="text" name="username" />
   <br />
   Password :
   <br />
      <input type="password" name="password1" />
   <br />
   Confirm Password :
   <br />
   <input type="password" name="password2" />
   <br /><br />
   <input class="btn btn=primary" type="submit" value="sign up !" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.POST['password1']==request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'username has already been taken'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.create(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html',{'error':'Password Not Match'})

    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html' ,{'error':'username or password is incorrect.'})        
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('home')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

**base.html**

```
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">
      <img src="{% static 'products/logo.png' %}" height=30 width=30 class="d-inline-block alighn-top" />
      Product Hunt
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}" onclick="">Logout</a>
          <form id="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" />
          </form>
          {% else %}
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```